# Array is empty when it is accepted by API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, fetch-api

I have FormData object to which I set an array of integers.

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=\"genre\"]:checked").forEach((e)=> genres.push(+e.value));

console.log(typeof(genres[0])); //number

if (genres.length > 0) {
    formData.set("genreFilters", JSON.stringify(genres));
}
```

I am sending this FormData object by `fetch()` to my ASP.NET API

```
fetch("/list", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
})
```

Whenever I check my request payload it appears to have selected values stored in the array
[image]

However, on the server side this array is always appear to be empty.

Here is my controller and request object on the server side.

```
public record GetAllBooksQuery : IRequest<GetAllBooksQueryResponse>
{
    public int Page { get; set; } 
    public int CountPerPage { get; set; } = 30;
    public int YearFrom { get; set; }
    public int YearTo { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; } = "Title";
    public string Direction { get; set; } = "Ascending";
    public int[] GenreFilters { get; set; } = Array.Empty<int>();
}

[Route("/list")]
public async Task<IActionResult> BookList(GetAllBooksQuery query)
{
    var response = await _mediator.Send(query);

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<GetAllBookResponse>(response));
}
```

**Note**: I tried to change content-type of my request to "application/json" but it didnt work.

Comment: You said you tried changing the Content Type to JSON, did you do that by setting a header or sending a JSON string as the body?

Comment: @gunr2171 by setting header.

Comment: Which JSON serialisation library are you using?

Comment: @SBFrancies I am not using any.

Comment: if you are using `new FormData()` `application/json` is not the valid type you should use `multipart/form-data`. Here is the MDN doc for it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: if not can you please share how you define the `formData` variable?

Comment: @LarsVonk I define it as this ```let formData= new FormData()``` in global scale

Comment: Then within your server you need to have some way to parse this i do not have experience with C# backends but within express you need a seperate parser as middleware for your endpoint to read the data

Comment: Just a 5 second look but your controller method may need a decorator like `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. Because I'm not used to work with javascript I didn't know that when I use JSON.stringify() it actually returns string that I need to parse eventualy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here might be that you are using the FormData object to send your data, but your server-side code expects a JSON payload. When you send data using FormData, it is automatically encoded as multipart/form-data, which is a different format than JSON.

To fix this issue, you can try changing your server-side code to accept multipart/form-data format, or you can modify your client-side code to send the data as JSON.

If you want to send the data as JSON, you can update your client-side code to use JSON.stringify to convert the data to a JSON string before sending it:

```
const data = {
  Page: 1,
  CountPerPage: 30,
  YearFrom: 2000,
  YearTo: 2022,
  Order: "Title",
  Direction: "Ascending",
  GenreFilters: genres
};

fetch("/list", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

Then, on the server-side, you should be able to deserialize the JSON payload using a JSON deserializer.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> BookList([FromBody] GetAllBooksQuery query)
{
  var response = await _mediator.Send(query);
  return Ok(_mapper.Map<GetAllBookResponse>(response));
}
```

**Note: You may also need to update the [Route("/list")] attribute on the server-side to [HttpPost("/list")].**

If you want to accept multipart/form-data format in your server-side code, you can use the [FromForm] attribute to bind the form data to your model.

```
[HttpPost("/list")]
public async Task<IActionResult> BookList([FromForm] GetAllBooksQuery query)
{
    var response = await _mediator.Send(query);
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<GetAllBookResponse>(response));
}
```

the [FromForm] attribute instructs ASP.NET to bind the form data to the GetAllBooksQuery model. This will work with the FormData object that you're currently using in your client-side code.

**Note: You should make sure that the name attribute of the file input element on the client-side matches the name of the property in your GetAllBooksQuery model.**